# oracle stored procedure - local variable behaving mysteriously

Tags: sql, oracle

This is how I am delcaring the local variables:

```
   team_counter number (38) := 0;
   username varchar2(50) := '';
```

This is how I am trying to use/see their value after using some select into statement:

```
    dbms_output.put_line(team_counter||'.'||username);
    if  team_counter< 30 AND username  <>'' then
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('yuhj');
    end;
    end if;
```

The second output is not being printed!
The first output is being printed as '1.tuser' which I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to compare a string with a 0 length string using an inequality operator.

Oracle assumes that 0 length strings are equivalent to NULL and will not evaluate comparisons that don't use the NULL specific conditional. [To quote](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm):

> Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of
>   zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future
>   releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings
>   the same as nulls.

Simply put this means that your IF statement should be:

```
if team_counter < 30 and username is not null then
   ...
```

As an additional note there's no need for the `begin ... end` around the `dbms_output.put_line`. As you're not catching any exceptions explicitly related to this call or declaring additional variables etc there's no real need.